Injured girl who can turn into a swan
I am trying to recall a movie where there is young guy who is going through a forest and comes across a girl who seems very weak and is bleeding. He brings her home and finds out that she transforms into a swan (i think) at night. This girl out of gratitude uses her feathers to make a gold kilt for the guy. The guy comes home one day and finds her dead. She is laying by the spinning wheel along with the gold kilt that she has been making for him. She is found in a weak state with multiple wounds on her body ..
This was probably in early early 90's when I watched it 

What genre is it, black and white or colour, and is this animated or live action?

I barely remember the details on it. It was not an animation film though. Along the lines of a fairy tale. I came across a plot that sounds similar to it 'The crane wife' but haven't been able to find any movie on it.

Tsuru (1988)
IMDb's Plot Summary:

Based on the folk tales "Repayment from a crane". One snowy night a beautiful woman named Tsuru (Crane) visits poor peasant Taiju sand says she will become his wife... 

Our Facebook group found this movie which sounds similar.
